# Ubuntu's bash does not honor INPUTRC

Tags: bash, readline, inputrc

I'm using `INPUTRC` to move the `.inputrc` file away from my home folder. It used to work (like with my `GNU bash, version 5.1.4`), but in bash `version 5.1.16`, I found that the `INPUTRC` is no longer honored.

```bsh
$ which $SHELL
/usr/bin/bash

$ $SHELL --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
. . .

$ env | grep INPUTRC
INPUTRC=/home/foo/bin/.inputrc

$ ls ~/.inputrc
ls: cannot access '/home/foo/.inputrc': No such file or directory
```

1. My `INPUTRC` file contains

```
set echo-control-characters off
set completion-ignore-case on
```

but neither is honored.

2. If I create a `~/.inputrc` file with above two lines, then they'd both work.
3. If I create a `~/.inputrc` file pointing to my `/home/foo/bin/.inputrc`, then both cases works as well.
4. however, if I remove the `~/.inputrc` file and use `INPUTRC` alone again, then neither cases works any longer.

So,

1. is there a bug in the bash version that i am using?
2. how can i tell whether bash honors `INPUTRC`?
3. how do you recommend to debug the issue?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @meuh, who has given a way to find the real cause, as I have found (even before posting the question) that if I do `bind -f /home/foo/bin/.inputrc` my terminal will be totally locked and will only response to '^C', even blindly typing `reset` into it and press return won't fix it, while my two-line version `bind -f` OK. So maybe my ancient .inputrc file (>20 years old) is causing some trouble with new bash, and using INPUTRC will trigger it more obviously than ~/.inputrc.

Through trial-and-error, I have found what is causing the problem and here it is:

```
$ cat .inputrc.nok
set editing-mode emacs
set horizontal-scroll-mode Off
set keymap emacs-meta
set echo-control-characters off
set completion-ignore-case on
```

With that,

- `bind -f .inputrc.nok` will lock the terminal session and
- pointing `INPUTRC` to it won't have any effect.

```bsh
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish (development branch)
Release:  22.04
Codename: jammy

$ apt-cache policy bash
bash:
  Installed: 5.1-6ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.1-6ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.1-6ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Actually, it is not only Ubuntu Jammy's problem, I went back to Ubuntu 18.04.1, and found that the behavior is exactly the same. However, everything is fine with @Kusalananda, so if anyone using Ubuntu, please give it a try. thx.

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue with `5.1.16(1)-release` on OpenBSD. Setting `INPUTRC` for a new shell session correctly initializes the Readline library with the settings from that file, even when that file is called something else than `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: Where do you set your `INPUTRC`? In your `profile` or `bashrc` or whereelse? Maybe too late?

Comment: You can explicitly reread the file with `bind -f /path/to/.inputrc`, which might help if you are trying to set INPUTRC in the current shell, and not just for subshells.

Comment: INPUTRC= **/home/foo/bin/.inputrc** and ls: cannot access **/home/foo/.inputrc** there appears to be some mismatch on the directory path.

Comment: @MC68020 I suppose OP wanted to demonstrate this way that the `INPUTRC` is set to the new path, while the default location file does not exist. Thus, if `INPUTRC` is not used, the `/etc/inputrc` will be used.

Comment: Thanks for the conformation @Kusalananda. Good point Philippos, I set and export it in ~/.bashrc. Maybe it has to be in the profile for version 5.1.16 now? Where do you set it Kusalananda?

Comment: I tested by setting `INPUTRC` in the environment before invoking a new shell: `INPUTRC=myfile bash`. You may need to set the variable in `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`, or somewhere so that it's set before an interactive shell is started.

Comment: Oh @Kusalananda, that may not work. I found that once the `set echo-control-characters off` is set in place, even launching any xterm from it with or without `-ls` it will still be in place. You need to totally log off to test it. That's the only way. I test it via ssh into another machine.

Comment: I tested this logged into a system with SSH and could see that setting or not setting `echo-control-characters` had an effect when starting a new shell the way that I described earlier.

Comment: Gotcha Kusalananda, Thanks for the conformation. @meuh, that might be the way to find the real cause, as I have found (even before posting the question) that if I do `bind -f /home/foo/bin/.inputrc` my terminal will be totally locked and will only response to '^C', even blindly typing `reset` into it and press return won't fix it, while my two-line version `bind -f` OK. So maybe my ancient .inputrc file (>20 years old) is causing some trouble with new bash, and using INPUTRC will trigger it more obviously than ~/.inputrc. I'll find out what it is and post back...

Comment: _"I'll find out what it is and post back..."_, finally found it through trial-and-error, see my updated OP. @Kusalananda, would you give it a try and see if it is also the case for you as well?

Comment: It does not make my shell unusable and I can verify that the settings are in effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135302/discussion-between-xpt-and-kusalananda).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://askubuntu.com/q/1400789/158442

Comment: @muru, same problem, different versions. See my "UPDATE 2:" above.